# JavaFX children vs items

Tags: javafx

Why in JavaFX some controls and layout has "children" property, when other has "items" property for essentailly same purpose? Is there any philosophy behind or may be some technical difference?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `getChildren()` method is defined in `Parent`, and consequently inherited by all subclasses of `Parent`, including `Pane`, and `Control`. The implementation of this method in `Parent` returns an *unmodifiable* list of child nodes (so it can be used for navigation through the scene graph, but cannot be used to manipulate what is contained in the parent).

The `Pane` class, and its subclasses, are designed to allow you to lay out other nodes in the scene graph. So `Pane` overrides `getChildren()` to return a *modifiable* list of these nodes: essentially the functionality of a `Pane` is to allow you to add nodes to it and remove them later if you need. The `Pane` subclasses position these nodes in various ways.

The `Control` class is a subclass of `Parent`, as controls contain other nodes. (E.g. a `ComboBox` contains a label or text field (if it's editable), and a button for displaying the drop down list.) `Control` inherits its `getChildren()` method from `Parent`, so it returns an unmodifiable list of the child nodes, but doesn't allow you to change that list (because if you removed nodes from a control, it would no longer behave in the way that control was designed to behave).

Some controls are designed to display other content. Trivially, a `Label` or `Button` can have a `graphic`, which is any node. The API for these classes allows you to change that node (via `setGraphic()`).

More complex controls allow you to add and remove a collection of nodes, as part of their intended functionality. So for example a `SplitPane` allows you to add as many nodes as you like, and remove them if you need. However, these are not the *only* nodes contained in the `SplitPane`. So the `getChildren()` method still has its implementation from the superclass: it returns an unmodifiable list of all the child nodes of the split pane: that includes the items you add, and the dividers (and potentially other things too). On the other hand, the `getItems()` method returns the list of nodes that you are allowed to change: so you can remove an item by calling `splitPane.getItems().remove(...)` (and the split pane will remove the corresponding divider from its child list as well).

Other complex controls have `getItems()` methods that might return specific types: e.g. `Menu.getItems()` returns an `ObservableList<MenuItem>` (so you can't put a `TableView` in a menu, you can only put menu items in there). Similarly `TabPane.getItems()` returns an `ObservableList<Tab>`.

So in short, the two things have completely different functionality. `getChildren()` returns the list of child nodes for the parent: it allows you to inspect and navigate the scene graph. `Parent` subclasses that specifically choose to do so may return a modifiable list, allowing you to use them as general containers.

The `getItems()` methods that some `Control` classes define are there to define *specific* functionality of that particular control. They still have `getChildren()` methods, which will return a different list.